# Add URL Rewrite Rule To Wordpress

Tags: wp-query, functions, permalinks, rewrite-rules, plugins-url

my link http://localhost/abm/?ct_city=la-jolla&search-listings=true

i want to this   http://localhost/abm/USA/la-jolla

Could you help please..

htpaccss file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /abm/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /abm/index.php? [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: WordPress provides pretty permalinks as an in-build core feature. You don't need to change apache rewrite rules in the `.htaccess`. 

Please specify what content types you use (post types/taxonomies) and what you want to actual show with the URL.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to **register** your expected variables. Something similar to:

```
function my_rewrite() {

    add_rewrite_tag('%ct_city%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%country%', '([^&]+)');

}
add_action('init', 'my_rewrite', 10, 0);
```

Then you need to create the rule which will redirect to your **abm** page. Note that you will need to discover your **abm**'s ID, since you will need to pass it in the rule.

```
function my_rewrite_rule() {

    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^abm/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?', //each ([^&]+) for each registered variable in their respective order
        'index.php?page_id=10&country=$matches[1]&ct_city=$matches[2]', //assign the variable to their respective value and the page_id
        'top'
    );

}
add_action('init', 'my_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

Finally, you will just need to edit your code to use `$wp_query->query_vars['ct_city'];` instead of `$_GET['ct_city'];`

Don't forget to save your Permalinks structure after the change so the rule is applied. Also note that this rule will only apply for the exact match: `/abm/country/city`. So if someone access `/abm/country` it will not get catched, so you will probably need to create special rules for those too.